# Adding a string parameter to OnClientClick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a link with this:

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("openWin({0}, {1}, {2});return false;",DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.component_id"), DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.control_id"), 'string value')%> ' />
```

This is failing because I'm ensure of how to add in the last string variable (indicating by the 'string value')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("openWin({0}, {1}, \"{2}\");
return false;"
,DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.component_id")
,DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.control_id")
,"string value")%> ' />
```

Single quote would cause a

> Parser Error Message

since you're also using single quotes for `OnClientClick` attribute. Escaping quotes with `\"` should get the job done.

**EDIT**

Use the following in order to avoid

> Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("openWin({0}, {1}, \"{2}\");return false;",DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.component_id"),DataBinder.Eval(Continer,"DataItem.control_id"),"string value")%> ' />
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, this is causing a 'Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant' error message

Comment: You should remove the new lines in my answer. I've done it like that, so that you can see it clearly. see the updated answer pls.

Comment: no problem. kindly mark as answer if it solves the problem so the other people can benefit from it.